# Change ActionBar color in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, colors, android-actionbar, xamarin

In Xamarin, how can I change the `ActionBar` background color and text color in a `Fragment`?

Here is the code that works in an `Activity`:

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.White);
ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable); 

int titleId = Resources.GetIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
TextView abTitle = (TextView) FindViewById(titleId);
abTitle.SetTextColor (Color.Black);
```

If I have the same code, for the same project, in a `Fragment`, I get the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'Android.App.ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable)'

At this line of code:

```
ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

And if I comment out the above line of code, I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

At this line of code:

```
abTitle.SetTextColor (Color.Black);
```

Also, I am placing this code in the `OnCreateView` function.

How does the code need to be changed so that it will work in a `Fragment`, rather than in an `Activity`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that to do this I need to manipulate the action bar from the activity

Here is the code:

```
public override void OnAttach(Activity activity)
{
    base.OnAttach(activity);
    var colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.White);
    activity.ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    var titleId = activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    var abTitle = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(titleId);
    abTitle.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Activity from the Fragment by using Activity property at any time, that
will return the Activity associated with the Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In a `Fragment`, the `ActionBar` view is usually handled through overriding the:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
```

callback method; after making sure you have called `SetHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `OnCreate()`.

It is possible that you are getting that `NullReferenceException` because OnCreateView() is being called before the ActionBar layout has been inflated.

Typically, this is what my method will look like:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    //Stops the menu being reinflated on configuration changes
    if(!menu.HasVisibleItems) 
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MenuLayout, menu);

    var myMenuItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.MyMenuItem);
    //Do stuff with your menu items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin users: you just have to cast your activity to `AppCompatActivity`.

```
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.black)

(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(color.toDrawable())
```