# Custom Theme not applying in FragmentActivity

Tags: android

My theme is not working I have seen this [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us/27847656#27847656) but not working
still grey only SplahScreen activity changed but  `MainActivity extend FragmentActivity` not:
Manifest:

```
   <application
     android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name="asasdsd.asdasdas"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher2"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
   >
    <activity
        android:name="app.sultan.sdcinfo.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="app.sultan.sdcinfo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
         >
    </activity> 

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`
```

I have localization and add theme file in every Language also in value-11 still not changed:Theme.xml

```
      `<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

   <style name="MyActionBar"    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#262626</item>
  </style>`
```

Tried with getActionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));

please look my project structure:splash screen activity then Main activity wich include navigation drawer with fragments in activitis color background  changed but not in the fragment

Comment: actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
  .parseColor("#ffdddf")));  //Try this

Comment: @Surender Kumar not working in MainActivity still grey

Comment: Had you removed android:theme="" from manifest.??

Comment: You are using `Light.ActionBar`, but set background as dark, why not directly use `DarkActionBar`

Comment: @Xingchen its for testing

Comment: @Surender Kumar Yes removed but now my activity and actiobar go to black color and I cannot change it to #ffffff for example

Comment: @Surender Kumar work with activities but not MainActivity maybe because its extends FragmetnActivity

Comment: Use this url for actionbar style generator   - http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not be able to change the actionbar background color because you are not using `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse` as the parent of `MyActionBar`

use

```
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"
```

instead of

```
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar
```

So your `theme.xml` would be like,

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

   <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">#262626</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Source : [Customize ActiobBar Background (Official Documentation)](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground)

Comment: still have problem,all activity actionbars are change but not the Main Activity maybe its because FragmentActivity in Main Activity changed only text color and still grey

Comment: I am usig  suppport library

Comment: @Sultan Did you include the xml code for support library in actionbar theme? What are you saying about text color?

Comment: Text color of  actionbar goes white and other activities like splashscreen in right color but not MainActivity,how to include:I am using import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

Comment: you mean <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> yes I include

Comment: @Sultan and `<item name="background">#262626</item>` did you include it?

Comment: @Sultan and be clear what do you wanna change? background color or text color? I have written code for background color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71276/discussion-between-sultan-and-apurva).

Comment: @Sultan I'm sorry, I also am stuck in my own app, let me solve my problem. I really can't.

Comment: please look my project structure:splash screen activity then Main activity wich include navigation drawer with fragments in activitis color background  changed but not in the fragment

Comment: @Sultan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993006/change-actionbar-color-in-a-fragment

Comment: worked for fragment and should I write it to every fragment there must be other way

Comment: Yes you have to write it individually for every fragment, there is no other way. And if my answer really helped you then please accept it. @Sultan

Comment: ok, so how can i add menu items on the actionbar in FragmentActivity